# Java add objects to ArrayList of objects in a for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

What I want to do is store arrays in an ArrayList of Objects of type Array int A[][]

My class Matrices:

```
public class Matrices {
    private int M[][];
    
    public int[][] getM() {
        return M;
    }

    public void setM(int[][] M) {
        this.M = M;
    }
}
```

My main code where I create an ArrayList of the Matrices class, I load an array that was already loaded in int[][]A, in each iteration k I create an object m of type Matrices and save the changes in each iteration k in an ArrayList of Matrices in Matrices.add(m), later I show what I want to obtain and what the code returns.

```
ArrayList<Matrices> matrices=new ArrayList<>();
//Crea matriz
int[][] A=panel.CreaMatriz();
//Fin Crea matriz
//Inicio Floyd 
for (int k = 0; k < nodos.size(); k++) {
    //agrega la matriz al ArrayList
    Matrices m=new Matrices();
    m.setM(A);
    matrices.add(m);//ERROR ONLY THE LAST OF ITERATION K IS SAVED
    //area.setText(panel.EscribeMatrices(matrices.get(k).getM()));
    //Fin agrega la matriz al ArrayList
    for (int i = 0; i < nodos.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nodos.size(); j++) {
            if (A[i][k]+A[k][j]<A[i][j]){
                A[i][j]=A[i][k]+A[k][j];   
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I what I expect is.

```
 0    3    1     ∞  
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3     ∞    ∞   0   

 0    3    1     ∞  
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0   

 0    3    1     ∞  
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0   

 0    3    1    2   
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0
```

The code only prints 4 times the last matrix created at the end of iteration k.

```
 0    3    1    2   
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0   

 0    3    1    2   
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0   

 0    3    1    2   
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0   

 0    3    1    2   
  ∞   0     ∞    ∞  
  ∞   4    0    1   
 3    6    4    0
```

Comment: `A` is reused for each iteration, so each iteration overwrites the previous values in `A`. `setM` does not copy `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int[][] A=panel.CreaMatriz();
```

`A` is a reference to an array of array (a matrix).

Every time you add it to `setM()` you add the **same** reference. So,  you might be thinking you're adding different arrays, but you're actually adding the same array and modifying the same array.

You need to create a new array each time, probably something like this:

```
A = new int[x][y]; // or get it from panel.CreaMatriz();
Matrices m=new Matrices();
m.setM(A);
matrices.add(m);
```

Note: By the way, the code convention is to name your variables and method in lowercase, so the following is preferred.

```
private int m[][];

....

int[][] a = panel.creaMatriz();
```